# Do all processes need all the data when invoking MPI_Comm_spawn?

Tags: mpi

I wonder if it is necessary that all the processes have the needed data when, for instance, an MPI_Comm_spawn is invoked.

When invoking this function, a root process is defined to drive the operation and this rank, obviously, must give the appropriate parameters to the function. I.e.:

```
MPI_Comm_spawn("./a.out", &argvs, maxprocs, info, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
```

If we know that *rank 0* is the root, do the other processes need to have set the variables: *argvs, maxprocs and info*? Or would it be enough to have that information in the *rank 0*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this seems clear from the documentation:
[MPI_Comm_spawn](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Comm_spawn.html)
where

> **argv** : arguments to command (array of strings, significant only at ***root***)
>   **maxprocs** : maximum number of processes to start (integer, significant
>   only at ***root***)
>   **info** : 
>   a set of key-value pairs telling the runtime system where and how to start the processes (handle, significant only at ***root***)

So the "other" processes don't need to set those above as far as I understand from the documentation.
Just keep in mind that is a collective call.

Answer (score 3):

Though the first four arguments to `MPI_Comm_spawn` are only significant at the designated root process, all processes in the communicator must make the call. Thus, they acquire the ability to communicate with the child job via the intercommunicator returned by `MPI_Comm_spawn`. In case you do not need that all ranks in the initial job be able to communicate with the child job, but only the root rank, you can use `MPI_COMM_SELF` instead of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`:

```
int rank;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
if (rank == 0) {
   MPI_Comm_spawn("./a.out", args, maxprocs, info, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,
                  &intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
}
```